# call parent class's method on a child class object java

Tags: java, oop

I have several classes that extend others. They both have a common method `result`. If I have an instance of `foobarbaz`, is it possible to call its parent's/grandparent's `result` method?

```
public class Foo {
    protected int resultA;
    public void calc(){ resultA=...} 
    public void result(){  return resultA;      }
}

public class Foobar extends Foo{
   protected int resultA;
   public void calc(){
       super.calc();
       resultB=...;
   } 
   public void result(){  return resultB;      }
}

public class Foobarbaz extends Foobar{
   protected int resultA;
   public void calc(){
       super.calc();
       resultC=...;
   }
   public void result(){  return resultC;      }
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is that each class does some extra calculation, besides the one of its parent. If user wants results from all 3 objects, the CalculationManager knows only Foobarbaz needs to be inited and calculated. Then it returns an reference to Foobarbaz to whoever is asking for Foo, because Foobarbaz will have a result for Foo as well.

Something like:

```
CalculationManager.add(Foo,Foobar,Foobarbaz);
//The following 3 calls return the same reference to a Foobarbaz object 
Foo       res1=CalculationManager.get(Foo);
Foobar    res2=CalculationManager.get(Foobar);
Foobarbaz res3=CalculationManager.get(Foobarbaz);
CalculationManager.doCalc();
//Iterate over each object to get result with the same method .result()
res1.result();        //---> resultA 
res2.result();     //---> resultB 
res3.result();  //---> resultC
```

Comment: Stupid question, but does what you have there work? I looks like it may.

Comment: It does not I can assure you. Java has something along the lines of dynamic method calling i.e. even if you label a dog a cat and then call getFood() it will return dogFood not catFood. *don't try to cast a dog as a cat please

Comment: The fact that you are tryong to does this show that you probably have a conception flaw in your program. Thus, you should spend time on fixing that conception flaw, instead of working around. Anyway, the sample code in the answer will allow you to do so.

Comment: If this is an investigation into OOP with Java then I think you've had plenty of response to keep you busy and happy ;-) If there's a real-life problem you're trying to deal with it might be better to give us details about that. Possibly there are other ways to achieve what you're trying to achieve (implementing an interface, some design pattern, ..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design Principle: *Favor composition over inheritance*

Get a copy of the Head First Design Patterns book and read about Strategy, Template and maybe also Factory patterns. Other patterns discussed in there will certainly come in handy elsewhere in this project or projects to come.

Possible scenario:

- have the Foo, FooBar and FooBarBaz classes extend from an abstract class AbstractFoo
- give AbstractFoo an attribute of type Calculator myCalc (and getter and setter to go with that)
- make Calculator an interface with method doCalc() to be implemented by classes that implement this interface
- create all possible Calculator implementations (CalculatorX, CalculatorY, ..) that implement their own version of doCalc()
- give AbstractFoo a public int calc() method that calls on the myCalc.doCalc() method to get the results you need

At the point where you worry about the different Calculator implementations have common code you can make use of the Template pattern or have them extend from a BaseCalculator etc.

This should keep you busy for some time but if you do it right and get the hang of it you'll find that using patterns like this helps you in many programming situations. Hence the name patterns, I guess ;-)

Comment: Book can be found [here](http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124) among other online bookstores.

Answer (score 2):

you would need something like this in each class:

```
Foo:  
    printParent()  
    {  
       super.printParent();  
    }  

FooBar:  
    printParent()  
    {  
       super.printParent();  
    }  

FooBarBaz:  
   printParent()  
   {  
      print(); // this is the top most class 
      //Incredibly fragile!
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible. You will have to instantiate an object of the parent class in order to call its print method.

e.g.

```
    FooBar f = new FooBar();
    f.print(); //foobar
```

Only from within the sub class can you use super keyword to access the super class' method.

Comment: if the method is static you don't have to instantiate

Comment: @Woot4Moo True. But the example inthe question does not include static methods.

Answer (score 0):

The super calls the method of the parent class